# getting string from string start wtih "abc" and end with "def"

Tags: java, string, split

I am using StringUtils (import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;) library to split string like:

```
String str = "ZXCVFMS2ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEFZXCVFMS3ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEFZXCVFMERRORDEF";
```

I need to take out string start with zxcv* and end with *def as

```
String tmp1 = "ZXCVFMS2ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEF";
String tmp2 = "ZXCVFMS3ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEF";
```

any help?

Solution thanks to @assylias :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ZXCV.*?DEF");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<> ();
while (m.find()) {
result.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: I am confused.  If you know what you are trying to extract, couldn't you just use `String.matches()` and check for the presence?

Comment: It would be better to use a regex to extract the info, because split is used when you have a unique separator.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `replaceAll`?

```
String tmp = str.replaceAll(".*(zxcv.*def).*", "$1"); //zxcvVariableCanChancedef
```

---

UPDATE following your edit

if you have a repeating pattern, you could use a `Matcher` - to avoid matching the whole string use the `?` quantifier [to make the match lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("zxcv.*?def");
String input = "15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<> ();
while (m.find()) {
  result.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: good solution thank you, what about if there is multiple String str = "15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND";

Comment: In that case my suggestion probably wouldn't work. You should phrase your question so that it corresponds to your actual problem, without over-simplification, with a clear input and output.

Comment: updated solution not working gives String tmp = "zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedef; I need tmp ="zxcvVariableCanChancedef" and tmp2 = "zxcvVariableCanChancedef"

Comment: @boy huh using that new input, the result is a list that contains two strings, exactly as you required.

Comment: my original string ZXCVFMS2ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEFZXCVFMS3ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEFZXCVFMERRORDEF your solutions output Log.d(TAG, "matcher : "+result.toString());   result: matcher : [ZXCVFMS2ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEFZXCVFMS3ZZ1012ZZ1012ZZ1000ZZ0923ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ0990ZZ1020DEFZXCVFMERRORDEF]

Comment: regular expressions are case sensitive... So `Pattern.compile("ZXCV.*?DEF");` or `Pattern.compile("zxcv.*?def", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`...

Comment: I did run patter with upper case

Comment: @boy with the pattern in upper case and the string you just gave, I get a list of 3 strings.

Comment: Thank you so much @assylias I did write wrongly the pattern to my compiler so its worked..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without any additional libraries using core [java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) functionality. For example:

```
String str = "15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(zxcv.*def).*");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // ==>  zxcvVariableCanChancedef
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String line = "15684zxcvAAAAAAAncedefABCDEND15684zxcvBBBBBBBBBBdefABCDEND";

**Last occurrence :**

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*(zxcv.*def).*").matcher(line);
    String tmp = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
    System.out.println(tmp);
```

**First occurence :**

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*?(zxcv.*?def).*").matcher(line);
```

**Biggest occurence (from first zxcv to last def) :**

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*?(zxcv.*def).*").matcher(line);
```

**All occurrences**

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*?(zxcv.*?def)").matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: if line is : String line = "15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND"; how to get tmp1 = zxcvVariableCanChancedef, and tmp2 = zxcvVariableCanChancedef

Comment: it returns the first match zxcvVariableCan123Chancedef . Are you looking for another result ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it because I wrote it using a text document, I don't have any java IDE in this computer. I hope it helps

```
    public String XXX()
    {
    int firstStorage = 0;
    int secondStorage = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < tmp.lenght() < i++)
    {
        if( tmp.substring(i,i+4).equals("zxcv"))
        {
            firstStorage = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = firstStorage ; i < tmp.lenght() < i++)
    {
        if( tmp.substring(i,i+3).equals("def"))
        {
            secondStorage = i + 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    return tmp.substring(firstStorage, secondStorage + 1);
}
```

Let me know if it is working or not. Have a nice day !!

Comment: @boy If I understood correctly, this is the answer. For examle, if you have a String str = "15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND" if will return "zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedef"

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str = "15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND15684zxcvVariableCanChancedefABCDEND";
            List<string> strList = new List<string>();
            while (str.IndexOf("zxc") >= 0 && str.IndexOf("def") >= 0)
            {
                var startIndex = str.IndexOf("zxc");
                var stopIndex = str.IndexOf("def");
                var item = str.Substring(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex + 3);
                strList.Add(item);
                str = str.Substring(0, startIndex) + str.Substring(stopIndex+3);
            }
```